# Multiple entries of same session in wtmp in RHEL 7.4

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, wtmp

I am getting 3 entries of the same session in a `wtmp` file. The weird entry is the third entry, which shows log out at the same time of login.

Can some help me in understanding which  configuration must be causing this issue?

```
user     pts/0        1XX.1XX.1XX.2XX  Tue May 22 20:31   still logged in
user     ssh          1XX.1XX.1XX.2XX  Tue May 22 20:31   still logged in
user     ssh          1XX.1XX.1XX.2XX  Tue May 22 20:31 - 20:31  (00:00)
```